# If democracy is ruled by the people what is ruled by share holders mean?

Tags: word-choice

Democracy means ruled by the people or population.

Some people call corporation as democracy too. That is the shareholders can vote who the CEO should be.

But the shareholders are not "people". So democracy is not a right term. Shareholdercracy? Doesn't feels right.

What would be the right term?

Also corporation is not only ruled by the shareholders, they also obey market mechanism.

What would be ruled by free market mean? Marketcracy?

Comment: You're getting into a political argument.  Especially given that, in any large corporation, all shareholders are not created equal.

Comment: Nobody rules a free market. That's why it is called 'free'. Market forces are allowed to work, unhindered by regulation or intervention.

Comment: @NigelJ - By that definition there's no such thing as a free market.

Comment: But the market rules corporations. The market mechanism I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You mean 'shareholders' doesn't correspond exactly to 'all the people [normally considered to belong to the relevant democratic nation, say]'.

But this is just a transferred / broadened sense.

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/democracy) gives the broader definition :

> **democracy**: a situation, system, or organization in which everyone [or at least the majority] has [/have] equal rights and opportunities,
>   and can help make decisions:
>
> *corporate democracy*
>
> *shareholder democracy*

So the accepted term ***is*** democracy; context or the use of 'shareholder democracy' will easily disambiguate.

........

I'm not aware of suitable more narrowly-defined terms. Though [Ken Kam](http://www.bly.com/newsite/Pages/forbes2.htm) seems to have virtually trademarked 'Marketocracy'.